# MSN took over WT. How can I revert this?

Tags: google-chrome

Shockwave stopped responding, and changed my default from Windows 8 and Google Chrome to Windows 8.1 and MSN.

I don't want this, I like windows 8 and I want to keep using Chrome. I do not want Bing.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. If you could clarify your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

Just fire up chrome - it'll ask you if you want it to be the default.